# Eclipse format code equivalent for IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Name says it. Is there an analogue for Ctrl-Shift-F in IntelliJ? I've searched, not found. Thanks much.

Comment: If you're using Android Studio it might be: ctrl+f8 or Ctrl+Alt+L

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+L</kbd>. I often use it together with incremental expression selection - <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+W</kbd> to format only the elements around my current edit position.